# Group cohomology and Klein four group

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $V$ be the Klein four group $\{1,\sigma,\tau,\sigma \tau\}$. Consider the $V$-module $A$ which is the cokernel of the map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[V]$ which sends $1$ to $1 + \sigma + \tau + \sigma \tau$, where we are considering the action of $V$ on $\mathbb{Z}[V]$ by translation. This induces an action of $V$ on $A$.

How to calculate the cohomology groups $H^i(V,A)$ for $i = 1,2,3$ for this action?

I thought about using the associated long exact sequence in cohomology, but I'm not sure which cohomology groups in this long exact sequence are zero and which aren't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TGhe cohomology groups $H^p(V,\mathbb Z[V])$ are zero when $p>0$, because the module $\mathbb Z[V]$ is coinduced (it is obvious that it is induced, and since $V$ is finite induced modules and coinduced modules coincide) This implies that the long exact sequence corresponding to your short exact sequence $$0\to\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z[V]\to A\to 0$$ splits into isomorphisms $$H^p(V,A)\cong H^{p+1}(V,\mathbb Z), \qquad\forall p\geq1,$$ and an exact sequence $$0\to H^0(V,\mathbb Z)\to H^0(V,\mathbb Z[V])\to H^0(V,A)\to H^1(V,\mathbb Z)\to 0$$

Comment: So if I get this correctly, this gives $H^i(V,A) \cong H^{i + 1}(V,\mathbb{Z})$ for all $i \geq 1$? This reduced the problem to calculating cohomology for the trivial action on $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: ok, and this gives $H^1(V,A) = (\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$, $H^2(V,A) = \mathbb{Z}/2$ and $H^3(V,A) = (\mathbb{Z}/2)^3$, if I'm right.